# Could not cast value of type '_SwiftValue'

Tags: swift, search, textfield

I have some code to add data

```
for v_p_item in v_p!{
        print(v_p_item["nama"])
        let names = v_p_item["nama"]
        let vpids = v_p_item["id"]
        self.vpid.append(vpids as AnyObject)
        self.SList.append(names as AnyObject)
        self.srcVp.theme.bgColor = UIColor (red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        print(self.vpid)
        print(self.SList)
        self.srcVp.filterStrings(self.SList as! [String])
        self.srcVp.itemSelectionHandler = { filteredResults, itemPosition in
            // Just in case you need the item position
            let item = filteredResults[itemPosition]
            print("Item at position \(itemPosition): \(item.title)")
            print(self.idvp)

            // Do whatever you want with the picked item
            self.srcVp.text = item.title
            self.idvp = item.title
            self.srcVp.endEditing(true)
            print(self.idvp)
        }
    }
```

and I have an error like this

> Could not cast value of type '_SwiftValue' (0x1050235f8) to 'NSString'
>   (0x103955568). 2019-04-12 13:45:03.552716+0700
>   mytelkomsat[10366:196119] Could not cast value of type '_SwiftValue'
>   (0x1050235f8) to 'NSString' (0x103955568).

[image]

Comment: Use native Swift types. No `NSArray`, no `AnyObject`, no `NSString`. This will solve your issue or at least you will get a more descriptive error message. And `UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)` is actually `UIColor.white`

Comment: can you give some example?

Comment: Please show the declaration of `vpid`, `v_p` and `SList`. By the way you should use more meaningful variable names.

Comment: var SList: [AnyObject] = [] ,,,,,  var vpid: [AnyObject] = []

Comment: From the perspective of the compiler `AnyObject` is *it’s reference type but I have no clue what static type it is*. As I said use (more specific) Swift types. I guess both arrays are supposed to contain strings so declare them as `[String]`.

Answer (score 0):

Doing force-wrap on `self.SList` in the line `self.srcVp.filterStrings(self.SList as! [String])` does mean that you are sure array objects are of `String` type.

Then you can define SList as:

```
    var SList = [String]() or, var SList: [String]? // initialize later on
```

And append objects as:

```
    if let names = v_p_item["nama"] as? String {
        self.SList.append(names)
    }
```

Same can be done for `self.vpid` according to the data type it is holding.